# How To Stop CSS Transition from "Flickering" on mobile nav

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, bourbon

I have created a [Codpen Pen](http://codepen.io/wptemple/pen/WbGKMv) showing the issue i'm experiencing. When you resize the browser to the media query, in this case <600px you will see a flash of the "toggled" off canvas mobile navigation which makes the resizing awkward and a bad user experience.

The issue is the transition on line 28:

```
@include transition(all .25s linear);
```

If I remove that line, it fixes all of the issues, but removes the transition that defeats the purpose of the mobile nav (it turns a smooth navigation to a clunky thing I don't want). How can I fix this? I've already tried:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEXaVP

Instead of using `transform:translateX` use `left`

```
.sliding-menu-content {
    left:-220px;
}

&.is-visible {
    left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, you are awesome. So there is one last problem. It's hard to notice on the demo, but I can clearly see it on my development environment. The background "flickers" to what it would be on the hover state. I changed the background on your demo to show you http://codepen.io/wptemple/pen/NPROGM.

Comment: Actually this causes another problem, the toggle no longer works on mobile. Any idea why @vitorinofernandes ?